# How to call function with parameters as setTimeout callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you call a function with parameters via JQuery's [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)?

This "works", but the function is called immediately:

```
var successFunc = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    alert("sf data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
    $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(data);
};
var successFuncWithTimeout = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    //alert("sfwt data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");

    setTimeout(successFunc(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored), 2000);
}
```

This waits for two seconds, but according to the alert, all parameters are `undefined`:

```
var successFuncWithTimeout = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    //alert("sfwt data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");

    setTimeout(function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
        alert("sf data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
        $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(data);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters don't need to be *passed* to the anonymous function, because they're already in scope. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169104/2736496) on Stack Overflow.)

```
var successFunc = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    alert("sf data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
    $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(data);
};
var successFuncWithTimeout = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    //alert("sfwt data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");

    setTimeout(function()  {
        successFunc(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Using the same concept, this also works:

```
var successFuncWithTimeout = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
    //alert("sfwt data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");

    setTimeout(function()  {
        alert("sf data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
        $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(data);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Or, you can use `.bind()` to attach the parameters to a callback.

Comment: FYI. That `return` in the `setTimeout` is misleading because it does nothing. It's not wrong because it does something wrong. Indeed it is harmless. But future developers will wonder why that `return` is there and wonder if there's a feature of javascript that they don't know about. Misleading code leads to wrong assumptions leads to bugs.

Comment: @slebetman: Fixed. It just returns `undefined`, so it should just be called.